# quantile from a list of dataframes

Tags: r

I have a number of dfs for which I need to calculate quantile such that it quantiles are distributed from 0 to max of all dfs. After that I would like to create breaks by capping 95 percentile. Something if I do individually for each df can be done like below but I need to do this on the fly and considering max of all dfs.

EDIT: x is a df with 400 columns and several thousand rows. I will have multiple such dfs with same number of columns but with different number of rows.

```
library(gplots)
quantile.range <- quantile(as.matrix(x), probs = seq(0, 1, 0.01))
palette.breaks <- seq(quantile.range["0%"], quantile.range["99%"], .001)
mycol <- colorpanel(n=length(palette.breaks)-1,low="white",mid="blue",high="red")
```

I have tried applying lapply but seem to be having some issues in my command:

```
dfList<-paste0("df", 1:10)
quantile.range <- lapply(dfList, function(x) {quantile(as.matrix(x), probs = seq(0, 1, 0.01))} )
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you make this reproducible? What is `x`? Further, which packages are required for `colorpanel` and is it relevant to the question?

Comment: @JasonAizkalns : Sorry about that. I have added some extra info on df structure and library.

Comment: Any error message?

Answer (score 1):

Hm, it seems that in your `lapply` you process `x`, which is a character instead of `data.frame`. Have you tried `get` as follow?

```
dfList<-paste0("df", 1:10)
quantile.range <- lapply(dfList, function(x) {quantile(as.matrix(get(x)), probs = seq(0, 1, 0.01))} )
```

Comment: @zymunaidi : Thanks that was useful although I was looking for creating a single quantile encompassing all dfs. But it helped in some way to reach there. Thanks again.

Comment: @Sudhir I see. Glad it helps. If you found solution to your question, please consider to share it through providing Answer